# Convert word document to xml code c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How to convert that word document to xml code like below?
I have a word document template. After converting word document to xml code, i will append my data table to body tag and generate word document. Please help. 
In my application,There is no posibility using Interop or some other dlls to customize the document, so i am trying like this.

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' 
xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<head><title>Time</title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<style>
<!-- /* Style Definitions */
@page Section1   
{size:8.5in 11.0in;    
margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ;    
mso-header-margin:.5in;    
mso-footer-margin:.5in; 
mso-paper-source:0;
} 
div.Section1   {page:Section1;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<div class=Section1><h1>Time and tide wait for none</h1>
<p style='color:red'><I>10/30/2014 5:37:16 PM</I></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A `.docx` document already contains the contents in XML. Try changing to extension to `.zip` and view the contents.

Comment: I believe, OpenXML library (available in NuGet as well) could solve your problem (recently I used it for Excel documents)

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: is it possible to change the extension? i am unable to change it to .zip. did u tried?

Comment: @YurySchkatula: can u pls giv me example or reference to achive this?

Comment: @HakunaMatata To do this first open word file in text editor.Then using text editor save as .zip file.Then you can extract the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenXML SDK 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

Allows you to manipulate Office files. The SDK is a bit unclear, though.

[Some help on converting Office files to XML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/the-flat-opc-format.aspx)